# Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD3 motherboard won't boot Debian image USB

Tags: boot, debian, motherboard, usb-flash-drive

I've downloaded the official Debian stable (Jessie) CD ISO and copied it directly to the USB (`dd if=debian.iso of=/dev/sdd`). But motherboard failed to boot - the motherboard status LED display shows value `50`, which means some USB keyboard problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me - do not use ISO image as the USB image (even if it is recommended as the easiest way).

Use USB image (downloaded from http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/boot.img.gz):

```
# zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdX
```

Then mount it and copy ISO image to the USB filesystem:

```
$ cp debian-8.6.0-amd64-CD-1.iso /mnt/usb/
```

**Now this USB drive will boot.**